# I cannot enter text into the "search programs and files" box on the start menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, toshiba-laptop, user-interface

I've just gotten a new computer with Windows 7 (same as the last computer - I'm generally familiar with it). Since I've gotten it, I have only rarely been able to type into the search box on the start menu.

The box is not greyed out; I can click into it and obtain a flashing cursor. However, as I say, the problem is intermittent - for example since I started typing this question, the box has started functioning normally.

The computer is a toshiba laptop, with most of the manufacturer's utility software still installed, until I figure out what is essential, and what is a menace.

Has anyone come across this behaviour, or know what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [similar problem is reported here](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-vista/912586-solved-cant-type-start-search.html); the suggested solution was to rebuild your search indexes?

[How to Rebuild Windows Vista Search Index](http://www.wikihow.com/Rebuild-Windows-Vista-Search-Index):

1. Open the Control Panel (Start -> Control Panel).
2. Select the "System and Maintenance" category.  Select the "System and Maintenance" category.
3. Under the "Indexing Options" category, click "Change how Windows searches".Under the "Indexing Options" category, click "Change how Windows searches".
4. Click the "Advanced" button.  Click the "Advanced" button.
5. When the User Account Control prompt appears, click "Continue".When the User Account Control prompt appears, click "Continue".
6. To rebuild your index, click the "Rebuild" button.To rebuild your index, click the "Rebuild" button. The number of indexed items will reset to zero, and Windows will begin to rebuild your index.

Comment: I wonder is "Windows Search" is disabled in Services?

Comment: The service was scheduled with "Automatic (delayed start)", which I imagine may have that effect when I start or wake my computer. I've set it to just "automatic".

Comment: I would return it to delayed start, read this...http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/delayed-start-feature-increases-options-for-windows-services/1552